# Why 1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) :3000/api/posts?: happens?

Tags: reactjs

There's an error in the post. I checked with f12, and it keeps making errors like this. Why do you think that's happening? And I wonder when this kind of error usually appears.There's an error in the post. I checked with f12, and it keeps making errors like this. Why do you think that's happening? And I wonder when this kind of error usually appears. This is the posts code

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Responsive from '../common/Responsive';
import Button from '../common/Button';
import palette from '../../lib/styles/palette';
import SubInfo from '../common/SubInfo';
import Tags from '../common/Tags';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const PostListBlock = styled(Responsive)`
   margin-top: 3rem;
`;

const WritePostButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
`;

const PostItemBlock = styled.div`
   padding-top: 3rem;
   padding-bottom: 3rem;
  /* 맨 위 포스트는 padding-top 없음 */
  &:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  & + & {
    border-top: 1px solid ${palette.gray[2]};
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    &:hover {
      color: ${palette.gray[6]};
     }
  }
   p {
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
 `;

const PostItem = ({ post }) => {
  const { publishedDate, user, tags, title, body, _id } = post;
  return (
    <PostItemBlock>
      <h2>
        <Link to={`/@${user.username}/${_id}`}>{title}</Link>
      </h2>
      <SubInfo
       username={user.username}
        publishedDate={new Date(publishedDate)}
       />
      <Tags tags={tags} />
      <p>{body}</p>
    </PostItemBlock>
  );
};

const PostList = ({ posts, loading, error, showWriteButton }) => {
  // 에러 발생 시
  if (error) {
    return <PostListBlock>에러가 발생했습니다.</PostListBlock>;
  }

  return (
    <PostListBlock>
      <WritePostButtonWrapper>
    {showWriteButton && (
      <Button cyan to="/write">
        새 글 작성하기
      </Button>
        )}
      </WritePostButtonWrapper>
      {/*  로딩 중 아니고, 포스트 배열이 존재할 때만 보여줌 */}
      {!loading && posts && (
       <div>
         {posts.map(post => (
            <PostItem post={post} key={post._id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </PostListBlock>
  );
};
```

export default PostList;